# Segmentation Fault in typecasting from unsigned int to char pointer

Tags: c, pointers, casting, char, integer

I'm new to c. Just learning.
What i am trying to do is initialize a variable type of unsigned int and then store address of an char type array in it and after that I am trying to use int as a pointer and print the array using the unsigned int but I'am getting segmentation fault, I don't know why?
It's printing value of memory address of char type array. But not the actual values at memory addresses.
Can someone please help?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char char_arr[4] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
    int i;

    unsigned int hackyPointer;
    hackyPointer = (unsigned int) char_arr;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("[hacky Pointer] now points to %p which contains value %c\n",hackyPointer, *((char *) hackyPointer));
        hackyPointer += sizeof(char);
    }

}
```

Comment: Type casting can't cause segfault. Please provide [mcve].

Comment: When size of address is not the same as sizeof int, then there will be an error in run-time. And if you turn warnings of your compiler on, it will tell you.

Comment: I have added source.. Please check again.. I'm using sizeof..

Comment: One obvious issue that can cause undefined behavior is that you are using `%p` to print an integer. The other is that your pointer size might be larger than can fit into `unsigned int`.

Comment: Probably a pointer is too big for an `unsigned int`. You can try `unsigned long` instead of `unsigned int`. Add output like this `printf("size of char* %d unsigned int %d unsigned long %d\n", sizeof(char*), sizeof(unsigned int), sizeof(unsigned long));` to see if the size is the problem.

Comment: But the code works when i remove typecasting part from printf() statement.. It prints the addresses using %p but when i try to print the char value using %c it causes segmentation fault. Thanks for quick reply.

Comment: Here is the output of          printf("size of char* %d unsigned int %d unsigned long %d\n", sizeof(char*), sizeof(unsigned int), sizeof(unsigned long));            size of char* 8 unsigned int 4 unsigned long 8

Comment: Why are you trying to store pointer values in unsigned integer variables?  Why not store pointer values in *pointer* variables?  You're bound to have less trouble...

Comment: Sorry guys I got it.. The problem was size of unsigned int. Thanks for your precious feedback.. thank you all guys..

Comment: @SteveSummit It;s a kinda assignment for me But i solved it thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    char char_arr[4] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
    int i;

    uintptr_t hackyPointer;
    hackyPointer = (uintptr_t) char_arr;

        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            printf("[hacky Pointer] now points to %p which contains value %c\n",( void * )hackyPointer, *((char *) hackyPointer));
            hackyPointer += sizeof(char);
        }
}
```

The program output is

```
[hacky Pointer] now points to 0x7ffff86d4224 which contains value a
[hacky Pointer] now points to 0x7ffff86d4225 which contains value b
[hacky Pointer] now points to 0x7ffff86d4226 which contains value c
[hacky Pointer] now points to 0x7ffff86d4227 which contains value d
```

You have to use an integer type that is able to contain values of pointers.

Comment: Thanks for your great suggestion.. I got it already it worked with unsigned long int.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are trying to fit a bigger number than `int` can store, that is if you are running `x64`.

In 64 bit systems, pointers have a size of 8 bytes and `int` is usually 4 bytes. Pointer addresses work like numbers so when you cast the pointer to `int`, the address will be truncated.

Casting the `int` back to a pointer it will now contain some other address that does not belong to your program which can result in a access violation, or in other words, a segmentation fault.

Use a bigger `int` to hold the address, cast it to an `int` pointer or use `uintptr_t` type which is guaranteed to be big enough to hold the address.